# Windows firewall - block all incoming connections enable/disable - CREATE SCRIPT

Tags: windows-7, script, firewall, windows-firewall

Is it possible to create script which enable/disable the first checkbox of windows 7 firewall settings (`Block all incoming connections....`)?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to block everything (all incoming and outgoing internet access) except those applications are in firewall white-list?](https://superuser.com/questions/1182658/how-to-block-everything-all-incoming-and-outgoing-internet-access-except-those)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**enable:**

```
netsh advfirewall set domainprofile firewallpolicy blockinboundalways,allowoutbound
```

**disable:**

```
netsh advfirewall set domainprofile firewallpolicy blockinbound,allowoutbound
```